# U-Boot Falcon Mode ft. RFS

Tags: linux, u-boot, kernel-panic

I am developing a system for BeagleBone Black. I am using Yocto Project to generate U-Boot, kernel and RFS.

In order to reduce boot time of this system, I am trying to set up U-Boot Falcon Mode. I am using this link as an instruction manual:

https://embexus.com/2017/05/07/fast-boot-linux-with-u-boot-falcon-mode/

In order to achieve this, first I downloaded the U-Boot version specified by this manual and did the required configuration changes. Afterwards, I used Yocto's toolchain (generated earlier by populate_sdk) to compile U-Boot, which went without problems.

Afterwards, I rebuilt the whole system (both kernel and RFS) with Yocto so it builds uImage instead of zImage, because Falcon Mode only supports uImage.

I am copying required files to BeagleBone Black using SD card. First 16 MiB of the card are unformatted and the rest is formatted as ext4 with label ROOT (/dev/mmcblk0p1). Using DD I copied the am335x-boneblack.dtb, MLO, u-boot.img and uImage to their respective areas in the first 16 MiB on SD card, then I mounted the ROOT partition at /mnt and extracted the RFS archive there.

After plugging in and turning the BeagleBone Black on, it boots from the SD card and I enter U-Boot to set up Falcon Mode. I use the following sequence of commands:

=> setenv bootcmd "setenv bootargs console=ttyO0,115200n8 consoleblank=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait init=/usr/bin/run-qtdemo.sh lpj=4980736; mmc read 83000000 80 180; mmc read 82000000 900 3000; bootm 82000000 - 83000000"

=> saveenv

=> mmc read 82000000 900 3000

=> mmc read 83000000 80 180

=> spl export fdt 82000000 - 83000000

=> mmc write 83000000 80 180

=> setenv boot_os 1

=> saveenv

=> reset

After the system restarts, SPL skips U-Boot and starts running the kernel, but kernel can't mount RFS which results in kernel panic. Here is the log file grabbed with Grabserial:

```
[0.000001 0.000001] 

[0.000397 0.000396] U-Boot SPL 2017.05-rc3-dirty (Apr 07 2019 - 18:01:50)

[0.096303 0.096303] Trying to boot from MMC1

[1.628782 1.532479] [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0

[1.633051 0.004269] [    0.000000] Linux version 4.10.17-yocto-standard (oe-user@oe-host) (gcc version 6.4.0 (GCC) ) #8 PREEMPT Thu Apr 11 14:47:37 CEST 2019

[1.645767 0.012716] [    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc082] revision 2 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d

[1.653299 0.007532] [    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache

[1.661486 0.008187] [    0.000000] OF: fdt:Machine model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black

[1.667507 0.006021] [    0.000000] cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x8e800000

[1.672140 0.004633] [    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback

[1.676907 0.004767] [    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.

[1.681718 0.004811] [    0.000000] AM335X ES2.1 (sgx neon)

[1.685356 0.003638] [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 64704

[1.693911 0.008555] [    0.000000] Kernel command line: 

[1.697114 0.003203] [    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)

[1.703286 0.006172] [    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)

[1.710582 0.007296] [    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)

[1.717670 0.007088] [    0.000000] Memory: 230608K/261120K available (6144K kernel code, 517K rwdata, 2216K rodata, 1024K init, 607K bss, 14128K reserved, 16384K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)

[1.733082 0.015412] [    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:

[1.737264 0.004182] [    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)

[1.743266 0.006002] [    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)

[1.749241 0.005975] [    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xd0800000 - 0xff800000   ( 752 MB)

[1.755347 0.006106] [    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xd0000000   ( 256 MB)

[1.761236 0.005889] [    0.000000]     pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)

[1.767210 0.005974] [    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)

[1.773212 0.006002] [    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0700000   (7136 kB)

[1.779217 0.006005] [    0.000000]       .init : 0xc0a00000 - 0xc0b00000   (1024 kB)

[1.785208 0.005991] [    0.000000]       .data : 0xc0b00000 - 0xc0b814e4   ( 518 kB)

[1.791293 0.006085] [    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc0b83000 - 0xc0c1acb0   ( 608 kB)

[1.797201 0.005908] [    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1

[1.804013 0.006812] [    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.

[1.809575 0.005562] [    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.

[1.815127 0.005552] [    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16

[1.818937 0.003810] [    0.000000] IRQ: Found an INTC at 0xfa200000 (revision 5.0) with 128 interrupts

[1.826555 0.007618] [    0.000000] OMAP clockevent source: timer2 at 24000000 Hz

[1.832174 0.005619] [    0.000012] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns

[1.840346 0.008172] [    0.000030] clocksource: timer1: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns

[1.849981 0.009635] [    0.000042] OMAP clocksource: timer1 at 24000000 Hz

[1.855065 0.005084] [    0.000475] clocksource_probe: no matching clocksources found

[1.861101 0.006036] [    0.000689] Console: colour dummy device 80x30

[1.865725 0.004624] [    0.001911] console [tty0] enabled

[1.869290 0.003565] [    0.001958] Calibrating delay loop... 996.14 BogoMIPS (lpj=4980736)

[1.875808 0.006518] [    0.089006] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301

[1.880669 0.004861] [    0.089171] Security Framework initialized

[1.884996 0.004327] [    0.089393] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)

[1.891937 0.006941] [    0.089447] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)

[1.899212 0.007275] [    0.090451] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok

[1.904399 0.005187] [    0.090568] ftrace: allocating 22859 entries in 68 pages

[1.909914 0.005515] [    0.156899] Setting up static identity map for 0x80100000 - 0x80100058

[1.916699 0.006785] [    0.158796] devtmpfs: initialized

[1.920157 0.003458] [    0.168460] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 3

[1.928166 0.008009] [    0.168880] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns

[1.939199 0.011033] [    0.169033] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)

[1.944809 0.005610] [    0.170429] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem

[1.950257 0.005448] [    0.171577] NET: Registered protocol family 16

[1.954909 0.004652] [    0.173421] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations

[1.962088 0.007179] [    0.189224] omap_hwmod: debugss: _wait_target_disable failed

[1.968037 0.005949] [    0.268956] cpuidle: using governor ladder

[1.972304 0.004267] [    0.298941] cpuidle: using governor menu

[1.976395 0.004091] [    0.304595] OMAP GPIO hardware version 0.1

[1.980664 0.004269] [    0.319164] hw-breakpoint: debug architecture 0x4 unsupported.

[1.986764 0.006100] [    0.356613] edma 49000000.edma: TI EDMA DMA engine driver

[1.992418 0.005654] [    0.360115] SCSI subsystem initialized

[1.996323 0.003905] [    0.360524] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: could not find pctldev for node /ocp/l4_wkup@44c00000/scm@210000/pinmux@800/pinmux_i2c0_pins, deferring probe

[2.009942 0.013619] [    0.361843] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer1

[2.015323 0.005381] [    0.418927] NET: Registered protocol family 2

[2.019914 0.004591] [    0.419806] TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)

[2.027148 0.007234] [    0.419875] TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)

[2.033788 0.006640] [    0.419924] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)

[2.040457 0.006669] [    0.420031] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)

[2.046548 0.006091] [    0.420073] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)

[2.053084 0.006536] [    0.420256] NET: Registered protocol family 1

[2.057633 0.004549] [    0.420915] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a8 PMU driver, 5 counters available

[2.066084 0.008451] [    0.423845] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=16 bucket_order=2

[2.072920 0.006836] [    0.439649] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)

[2.080576 0.007656] [    0.439734] io scheduler noop registered

[2.084665 0.004089] [    0.439761] io scheduler deadline registered

[2.089118 0.004453] [    0.439820] io scheduler cfq registered (default)

[2.094047 0.004929] [    0.440857] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins at pa f9e10800 size 568

[2.101416 0.007369] [    0.443580] omap_uart 44e09000.serial: no wakeirq for uart0

[2.107256 0.005840] [    0.443838] 44e09000.serial: ttyO0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 158, base_baud = 3000000) is a OMAP UART0

[2.117028 0.009772] [    0.932508] console [ttyO0] enabled

[2.121283 0.004255] [    0.936761] [drm] Initialized

[2.139157 0.017874] [    0.954612] brd: module loaded

[2.143134 0.003977] [    0.958557] mtdoops: mtd device (mtddev=name/number) must be supplied

[2.150543 0.007409] [    0.965981] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed

[2.155208 0.004665] [    0.970701] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice

[2.161919 0.006711] [    0.977377] omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: already running

[2.167438 0.005519] [    0.982894] omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: rtc core: registered 44e3e000.rtc as rtc0

[2.175388 0.007950] [    0.990840] i2c /dev entries driver

[2.180034 0.004646] [    0.995447] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: Got CD GPIO

[2.283928 0.103894] [    1.099232] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable

[2.294222 0.010294] [    1.109707] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 59b4

[2.303282 0.009060] [    1.116858] oprofile: using arm/armv7

[2.309948 0.006666] [    1.117008] u32 classifier

[2.313163 0.003215] [    1.117010]     Actions configured

[2.317326 0.004163] [    1.117950] NET: Registered protocol family 10

[2.322162 0.004836] [    1.123153] Segment Routing with IPv6

[2.325826 0.003664] [    1.123227] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver

[2.337296 0.011470] [    1.124014] NET: Registered protocol family 17

[2.341983 0.004687] [    1.124062] Key type dns_resolver registered

[2.346677 0.004694] [    1.124074] omap_voltage_late_init: Voltage driver support not added

[2.353365 0.006688] [    1.124224] ThumbEE CPU extension supported.

[2.357928 0.004563] [    1.148163] Key type encrypted registered

[2.362951 0.005023] [    1.178445] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 SD    7.23 GiB 

[2.369681 0.006730] [    1.185172]  mmcblk0: p1

[2.412548 0.042867] [    1.227821] random: fast init done

[2.420917 0.008369] [    1.236301] tps65217 0-0024: TPS65217 ID 0xe version 1.2

[2.453160 0.032243] [    1.268553] mmc1: switch to bus width 8 failed

[2.460255 0.007095] [    1.275597] mmc1: new high speed MMC card at address 0001

[2.466603 0.006348] [    1.282097] mmcblk1: mmc1:0001 M62704 3.56 GiB 

[2.471676 0.005073] [    1.287174] mmcblk1boot0: mmc1:0001 M62704 partition 1 2.00 MiB

[2.478235 0.006559] [    1.293723] mmcblk1boot1: mmc1:0001 M62704 partition 2 2.00 MiB

[2.485966 0.007731] [    1.301413]  mmcblk1: p1

[2.569127 0.083161] [    1.384356] tda998x 0-0070: found TDA19988

[2.574350 0.005223] [    1.389814] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: bound 0-0070 (ops tda998x_ops)

[2.580708 0.006358] [    1.396185] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).

[2.587651 0.006943] [    1.403143] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.

[2.594200 0.006549] [    1.409684] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes - going 1024x768

[2.615149 0.020949] [    1.425004] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48

[2.621760 0.006611] [    1.437276] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: fb0:  frame buffer device

[2.657146 0.035386] [    1.472514] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: bus 0 rev0.11 at 400 kHz

[2.663349 0.006203] [    1.478830] console [netcon0] enabled

[2.667345 0.003996] [    1.482846] netconsole: network logging started

[2.672191 0.004846] [    1.487700] omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: setting system clock to 2000-01-01 00:00:47 UTC (946684847)

[2.682637 0.010446] [    1.498110] VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6

[2.690693 0.008056] [    1.506199] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:

[2.699671 0.008978] [    1.515180] 0100            4096 ram0 

[2.703664 0.003993] [    1.515185]  (driver?)

[2.706178 0.002514] [    1.521661] 0101            4096 ram1 

[2.710182 0.004004] [    1.521665]  (driver?)

[2.712678 0.002496] [    1.528199] 0102            4096 ram2 

[2.716703 0.004025] [    1.528202]  (driver?)

[2.719194 0.002491] [    1.534715] 0103            4096 ram3 

[2.723162 0.003968] [    1.534719]  (driver?)

[2.725684 0.002522] [    1.541183] 0104            4096 ram4 

[2.729650 0.003966] [    1.541186]  (driver?)

[2.732162 0.002512] [    1.547675] 0105            4096 ram5

[2.738608 0.006446] [    1.547679]  (driver?)

[2.743034 0.004426] [    1.558524] 0106            4096 ram6 

[2.749129 0.006095] [    1.558528]  (driver?)

[2.753662 0.004533] [    1.569171] 0107            4096 ram7 

[2.759692 0.006030] [    1.569175]  (driver?)

[2.764272 0.004580] [    1.579769] 0108            4096 ram8 

[2.770397 0.006125] [    1.579773]  (driver?)

[2.775025 0.004628] [    1.590351] 0109            4096 ram9

[2.780838 0.005813] [    1.590355]  (driver?)

[2.785335 0.004497] [    1.600824] 010a            4096 ram10 

[2.791363 0.006028] [    1.600827]  (driver?)

[2.795817 0.004454] [    1.611308] 010b            4096 ram11 

[2.801780 0.005963] [    1.611312]  (driver?)

[2.806241 0.004461] [    1.621706] 010c            4096 ram12 

[2.812267 0.006026] [    1.621709]  (driver?)

[2.816625 0.004358] [    1.632123] 010d            4096 ram13 

[2.822554 0.005929] [    1.632127]  (driver?)

[2.826947 0.004393] [    1.642430] 010e            4096 ram14 

[2.832813 0.005866] [    1.642433]  (driver?)

[2.837177 0.004364] [    1.652655] 010f            4096 ram15 

[2.843025 0.005848] [    1.652658]  (driver?)

[2.847390 0.004365] [    1.662806] b300         7584768 mmcblk0 

[2.853348 0.005958] [    1.662811]  driver: mmcblk

[2.858089 0.004741] [    1.673590]   b301         7568384 mmcblk0p1 fe2505fb-01

[2.865468 0.007379] [    1.673594] 

[2.868861 0.003393] [    1.684355] b308         3735552 mmcblk1 

[2.874841 0.005980] [    1.684359]  driver: mmcblk

[2.879528 0.004687] [    1.695009]   b309         3734528 mmcblk1p1 00000000-01

[2.886829 0.007301] [    1.695012] 

[2.890104 0.003275] [    1.705617] b318            2048 mmcblk1boot1 

[2.896510 0.006406] [    1.705621]  (driver?)

[2.900640 0.004130] [    1.716144] b310            2048 mmcblk1boot0 

[2.906998 0.006358] [    1.716147]  (driver?)

[2.911117 0.004119] [    1.726599] VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

[2.918851 0.007734] [    1.734375] User configuration error - no valid root filesystem found

[2.927263 0.008412] [    1.742775] Kernel panic - not syncing: Invalid configuration from end user prevents continuing

[2.938023 0.010760] [    1.753547] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper Not tainted 4.10.17-yocto-standard #8

[2.947238 0.009215] [    1.762660] Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)

[2.955222 0.007984] [    1.770748] [<c010f250>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c010c0cc>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)

[2.965067 0.009845] [    1.780595] [<c010c0cc>] (show_stack) from [<c039d94c>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)

[2.974413 0.009346] [    1.789938] [<c039d94c>] (dump_stack) from [<c01f76f8>] (panic+0xc0/0x234)

[2.983431 0.009018] [    1.798938] [<c01f76f8>] (panic) from [<c0a013c4>] (mount_block_root+0x22c/0x2d0)

[2.993078 0.009647] [    1.808606] [<c0a013c4>] (mount_block_root) from [<c0a015b0>] (mount_root+0x60/0x78)

[3.003082 0.010004] [    1.818584] [<c0a015b0>] (mount_root) from [<c0a01748>] (prepare_namespace+0x180/0x1c0)

[3.013416 0.010334] [    1.828880] [<c0a01748>] (prepare_namespace) from [<c0a00f54>] (kernel_init_freeable+0x220/0x27c)

[3.024639 0.011223] [    1.840145] [<c0a00f54>] (kernel_init_freeable) from [<c06a9674>] (kernel_init+0x18/0x11c)

[3.035327 0.010688] [    1.850825] [<c06a9674>] (kernel_init) from [<c0107798>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x3c)

[3.045294 0.009967] [    1.860793] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Invalid configuration from end user prevents continuing
```

Based on the log file, either:

1) Kernel doesn't want to boot RFS from SD card for some reason.

2) U-boot environment variable bootargs is not saved properly and the kernel does not recognize root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 as a value for root parameter.

Could anyone shed some ideas about how I could fix this?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently struggling with Falcon mode myself.  I'm pretty sure you need to set `bootargs` to whatever you want to pass on to the kernel before you do `spl export`.  `spl export` edits the FDT to have the `bootargs`.  The error message seems consistent with an empty kernel command line.  Your `bootcmd` will not be executed in Falcon mode.